# How to draw vector/matrix diagram [image attached]

Tags: diagrams

How can I draw the following which depicts certain vector and matrix operations.

[image: Vector Mixture vs Tensor Based]

Update: I modified @rpapa 's solution a bit and to get the following.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,backgrounds}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{background}=[rectangle, fill=green!85, inner sep=0.1cm, rounded corners=2.5mm, line width=0.3mm]

\newcommand{\Vcol}[2]{
  \foreach \nn in {1,2,...,5}{
    \node[circle,draw,fill=#2, line width=0.25mm] (#1-\nn) at (0,{-1.5*\nn em}) {};
  }
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node [background, fit=(#1-1) (#1-5), draw] (col-#1) {};
  \end{pgfonlayer}
}

\newcommand{\VcolS}[3]{
  \foreach \nn in {1,2,...,5}{
    \node[circle,draw, shade, left color=#2, right color=#3, line width=0.25mm] (#1-\nn) at (0,{-1.5*\nn em}) {};
  }
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node [background, fit=(#1-1) (#1-5), draw] (col-#1) {};
  \end{pgfonlayer}
}

\newcommand{\VcolD}[3]{
  \node[circle,draw,fill=#2, line width=0.25mm] (#1-1) at (0,{-1.5*1 em}) {};
  \foreach \nn in {2,...,5}{
    \node[circle,draw,fill=#3, line width=0.25mm] (#1-\nn) at (0,{-1.5*\nn em}) {};
  }
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node [background, fit=(#1-1) (#1-5), draw] (col-#1) {};
  \end{pgfonlayer}
}


\newcommand{\Mat}[2]{
  \foreach \nr in {1,2,...,5}{
    \foreach \nc in {1,2,...,5}{
      \node[circle,draw,fill=#2, line width=0.25mm] (#1-\nr-\nc) at ({1.5*\nr em},{-1.5*\nc em}) {};
    }
  }
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node [background, fit=(#1-1-1) (#1-5-5), draw] (col-#1) {};
  \end{pgfonlayer}
}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[xshift=0]
  \Vcol{a}{yellow!85}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=3em]
  \Vcol{b}{red!85}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=6em]
  \VcolS{c}{yellow}{red}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=9em]
  \Mat{e}{yellow!85}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=19.5em]
  \Vcol{b}{red!85}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=22.5em]
  \VcolD{b}{brown!85}{red!45}
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're asking an *awful* lot, have you tried anything? Yes, you could draw this with something like TikZ, course you could. But I'm not really sure that would be the best use of your time, this is something better drawn in image creation software - is there any reason why you can't just include this image? TikZ is really meant, I think, for technical drawings, or really really simple stuff. This doesn't even have any text, so it's not really clear to me why it couldn't be included as is. In any case, TikZ is a massive learning curve, and I wouldn't start by trying to draw this

Comment: You may start with the Tikz/PGF package for drawing diagrams. http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/ and http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf. Some examples http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/all/. You are more likely to get help if you add a minimum working example.

Comment: See if this example is is useful as a strting point. http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/matrix-multiplication/. It shows how to make matrices, put circles around elements, and draw arrows.

Comment: @Au101 I agree that this is not meant to be drawn in TeX but in an image creation software. I posted the question to check if there are any 'magical' packages (that I do not know of) which make drawing this easy. I would need this to show various deep learning architectures (some examples: [RNN Encoder-Decoder](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nPy6M.png), [MV RNN](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hsfkA.png) ) for my project and thesis. I tried to modify rpapa's answer as updated in the post. I think, using Inkscape is the best thing for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a beginning with tikz

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\Vcol}[2]{
\foreach \nn in {1,2,...,5}{
\node[circle,draw, fill=#2](#1-\nn) at (0,{-1.5*\nn em}){};
}
\node[fit=(#1-1) (#1-5), draw](col-#1){};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[xshift=0]
\Vcol{a}{red}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=3em]
\Vcol{b}{green}
\end{scope}


\begin{scope}[xshift=6em]
\Vcol{b}{green!50!red}
\end{scope}



\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here a supplement to your code to draw arrows

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,backgrounds}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{background}=[rectangle, fill=green!85, inner sep=0.1cm, rounded corners=2.5mm, line width=0.3mm]

\newcommand{\Vcol}[2]{
  \foreach \nn in {1,2,...,5}{
    \node[circle,draw,fill=#2, line width=0.25mm] (#1-\nn) at (0,{-1.5*\nn em}) {};
  }
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node [background, fit=(#1-1) (#1-5), draw] (col-#1) {};
  \end{pgfonlayer}
}

\newcommand{\VcolS}[3]{
  \foreach \nn in {1,2,...,5}{
    \node[circle,draw, shade, left color=#2, right color=#3, line width=0.25mm] (#1-\nn) at (0,{-1.5*\nn em}) {};
  }
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node [background, fit=(#1-1) (#1-5), draw] (col-#1) {};
  \end{pgfonlayer}
}

\newcommand{\VcolD}[3]{
  \node[circle,draw,fill=#2, line width=0.25mm] (#1-1) at (0,{-1.5*1 em}) {};
  \foreach \nn in {2,...,5}{
    \node[circle,draw,fill=#3, line width=0.25mm] (#1-\nn) at (0,{-1.5*\nn em}) {};
  }
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node [background, fit=(#1-1) (#1-5), draw] (col-#1) {};
  \end{pgfonlayer}
}


\newcommand{\Mat}[2]{
  \foreach \nr in {1,2,...,5}{
    \foreach \nc in {1,2,...,5}{
      \node[circle,draw,fill=#2, line width=0.25mm] (#1-\nr-\nc) at ({1.5*\nr em},{-1.5*\nc em}) {};
    }
  }
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node [background, fit=(#1-1-1) (#1-5-5), draw] (col-#1) {};
  \end{pgfonlayer}
}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[xshift=0]
  \Vcol{a}{yellow!85}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=3em]
  \Vcol{b}{red!85}
\end{scope}


\begin{scope}[xshift=6em]
  \VcolS{c}{yellow}{red}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=9em]
  \Mat{e}{yellow!85}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=19.5em]
  \Vcol{f}{red!85}
\end{scope}


\begin{scope}[xshift=22.5em]
  \VcolD{g}{brown!85}{red!45}
\end{scope}

\foreach \i in{1,2,...,5}{
\draw[<->,blue,thick](a-\i)--(b-\i);}

\node [font=\large\bfseries] at ($(b-3)!0.5!(c-3)$){=};
\node [font=\large\bfseries] at ($(f-3)!0.5!(g-3)$){=};

\draw[->,blue,thick](e-5-1.center)--(e-5-5.center)--(f-5);
\draw[->,blue,thick](e-4-1.center)--(e-4-4.center)--($(e-5-4.center)+(-0.05,0)$)arc(180:00:0.05)--(f-4);
\draw[->,blue,thick](e-3-1.center)--(e-3-3.center)--($(e-4-3.center)+(-0.05,0)$)arc(180:00:0.05)--($(e-5-3.center)+(-0.05,0)$)arc(180:00:0.05)--(f-3);
\draw[->,blue,thick](e-2-1.center)--(e-2-2.center)--($(e-3-2.center)+(-0.05,0)$)arc(180:00:0.05)--($(e-4-2.center)+(-0.05,0)$)arc(180:00:0.05)--($(e-5-2.center)+(-0.05,0)$)arc(180:00:0.05)--(f-2);
\draw[->,blue,thick](e-1-1.center)--+(0,0.5)-|(f-1.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]